# Is “by way of conclusion" more formal than "In conclusion"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

The OP of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/168882/17712 claims that:

> "In conclusion" is common, while "by way of conclusion" is quite formal.

Is that true, or do “by way of conclusion" and "In conclusion" have the same level of formality?

---

For sure "In conclusion" is more common though:

[Google Ngram Viewer: *by way of conclusion* vs. *in conclusion*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+way+of+conclusion%2Cin+conclusion&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cby%20way%20of%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20way%20of%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20way%20of%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20Way%20of%20Conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBY%20WAY%20OF%20CONCLUSION%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20way%20of%20Conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIn%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20conclusion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20Conclusion%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: *By way of conclusion* is flatulent.

Comment: @TRomano Agreed, I get the feeling that the author had some kind of personal bias towards the phrase "by way of conclusion" and felt like injecting it into their work. I've never heard or seen it before in my life, and it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

We have similar phrases, including *by way of introduction* and *by way of summary.* These are not a matter of formality but of an author's style.